# Route (some) requests from WordPress directory to Codeigniter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have a website:

```
mysite.com -> basic wordpress site
mysite.com/app -> php codeigniter app
mysite.com/app/profile/view/name.surname -> user profile in my codeigniter app
```

THE PROBLEM:

I want to route the requests from:

```
mysite.com/name.surname
```

...to the user profile of "name.surname" on my codeigniter app:

```
mysite.com/app/profile/view/name.surname
```

Every "profile" identifier in the url slug contains at least a dot (.) like profiles on facebook. Therefore, if any given slug contains a (.) then I know for sure that it is a user profile.

What is the best way to accomplish this behaviour?

[EXAMPLES AND VISUAL EXPLANATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfbPo.png)

Comment: A few years ago I wrote a little library that did something similar. Maybe it will help you. I'll leave you the link: https://bitbucket.org/osferanet/ciwp-auth/wiki/Home

Comment: Hi Alfonso, the profiles are created directly inside the Codeigniter app. WordPress is just useful to us for our "company site", it does not have to do with user profiles.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting a route with callback, assuming *profile* is your controller and *view* your method:

```
$route['(:any)']=function ($user){      
        $user=explode('.',$user);
        if(array_key_exists(1,$user)){
            // check if array has 2nd element and create route
            return "profile/view/$user[0]/$user[1]";
        }else{
            // route to index function
            return "profile/index";
        }
};
```

in the function *view* of controller *profile* you can get name and surname like this:

```
function view($n, $sn){
    echo "name= $n; surname= $sn";
}
```

about [Codeigniter Uri Routing with Callback](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#callbacks)

Comment: /app is not a controller. /app is the directory in which I am hosting the codeigniter app. I have uploaded a better example picture in the first post :)

-app
-wp-content
-wp-admin
-etc...

Comment: the default controller is $route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard/admin_view'; in the example problem instead, the controller is 'profile'

Answer (score 0):

I know your question specifies .htaccesss, but maybe this will help you. Include an index.php file like the one below:

```
<?php
      $uri_path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
      $uri_segments = explode('/', $uri_path);
      if(strpos($uri_segments[0],'.')===false){
                include 'wordpress_index.php';
      }else{
                include 'codeigniter_index.php';
      }
```

Its only function will be to determine which application to load based on the existence of a point in the first segment of your url.

Comment: Hi Alfonso, I had to change $uri_segments from 0 to 1 to make it work (element 0 of that array is a blank string)… but Codeigniter gives this error: "Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php", how can I set it in a way that works in every situation? (mysite.com/name.surname and also mysite.com/app/controller/action/)?

Comment: Try this: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html#relocating-your-application-directory